# Unable to run Flask for a Python document in Git-Bash on Windows 10

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am having issues running flask as required by my assignment. My assignment states the following:

[image]

I am trying this through git-bash and have also tried through Windows Powershell with the same errors. I have referenced stackflow articles which state to use `export FLASK_APP=app.py` as a code line but haven't had luck with those. Do I need to reinstall Flask? Not sure where to go or what to do. My computer software is Windows 10. Below are my attempts to run flask within Git-Bash along with the code within my app.py document:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your file you never actually tell Flask to run, just to initialize. You want something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__': # Run flask when the file is called
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

That will get flask to run, and the `host="0.0.0.0"` will make it accessible to your computer. I don't know if WSL forwards it's ports, but if it does the app should be available on localhost:5000 in your browser (though not much will happen since this is an empty project).

You can validate this is working by modifying that example to:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Is called on the homepage"""
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__': # Run flask when the file is called
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Then go to localhost:5000 in your browser, and it should say "Hello"